# Force (require) json API loading to complete (finish) before subsequent use in viewDidLoad() swift

Tags: json, swift, api, viewdidload, completion

I need to do some initialization in viewDidLoad after my json data has been loaded (using loadResultsFromItunesApi()). The problem is that it never finishes until later. Any references to the json data set within super.viewDidLoad bomb the application. The process is asynchronous as can be seen by the timing shown in the following debug print:

```
    0  ET msec: 0.153
    1  ET msec: 0.567
    10  ET msec: 2.413
    11  ET msec: 2.472
    2  ET msec: 49.038
    3  ET msec: 52.827
    6  ET msec: 52.984
    4  ET msec: 55.767
    5  Lover
```

When I try to use the json data within super.viewDidLoad I get the following debug print:

```
    0  ET msec: 0.133
    1  ET msec: 0.506
    10  ET msec: 2.725
    Fatal error: Index out of range:
```

Thanking you ahead of time for any ideas!! Here is the code:
'''

```
import UIKit
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var results = [Result]()
    var start:Int64 = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        start = Date().toMicroSeconds()
        print("0 ",printMsecFromStart())
        loadResultsFromItunesApi()
        print("11 ",printMsecFromStart())
        // This next statement bombs the app but okay later
        //resultsLabel.text = results[0].trackName
    }
    @IBAction func printResults(_ sender: Any) {
        resultsLabel.text = results[20].trackName
    }
    func loadResultsFromItunesApi()  {
        print("1 ",printMsecFromStart())
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song") else {
            print("Invalid URL"); return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            print("2 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    print("3 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("4 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                        print("5 ",self.results[0].collectionName)
                    }
                    print("6 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
                    return
                }
                print("8 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
            }
            print("9 ",self.printMsecFromStart())
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error ??")")
        }.resume()
        print("10 ",printMsecFromStart())
    }
    func printMsecFromStart() -> String {
        let et = Float(Date().toMicroSeconds() - start)/1000.0
        return "ET msec: " + String(et)
    }
    func printDate(string: String) {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
        print(string + formatter.string(from: date))
    }
}
extension Date {
    func toMicroSeconds() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000000)
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Though it's possible to force viewDidLoad() to wait until the iTunes request completes with a DispatchGroup, I would not recommend blocking that method - if the request takes awhile it will make your app unresponsive.

Instead, put the downstream initialization you need to do in a separate func, and call it from that DispatchQueue.main.async block you already have written when the json data is returned.

If the problem you're trying to avoid is how the UI looks before the data is retrieved, there are a few ways to handle that including having your view content initially hidden and showing it (maybe even with a little animation) after the data is retrieved. If you find in testing there's usually a noticeable lag you could add an activity indicator in the view to show the user it's loading (without blocking the main thread).

Your URLRequest block currently isn't handling any request errors (apart from the print statement), so you might also create a func to handle errors and call it similarly.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I think I understand what you were telling me, but I really need to be able to do things in the set up that are dependent on the API. I found a solution by adapting  Axel Kee's 7 May 2019 DownloadOperation class found here:
// https://fluffy.es/download-files-sequentially/
// SequentialDownload-master

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this problem for weeks now. After I posted the question for help I ran across a post by Axel Kee 7 May 2019 on:
Download files sequentially using URLSession inside OperationQueue. https://fluffy.es/download-files-sequentially/
By using the approach provided by his class DownloadOperation : Operation {…} I  was able to solve my problem. I understand Corbell’s warning, but since I need to do setup operations that depend on Api results this approach provided the solution I need. Maybe there is a better way than this, and maybe this would help someone else. It will also expose Axel Kee’s approach to downloading multiple files to others.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var start:Int64 = 0
    var urlLocal: URL?
    var response:Response?
    var session : URLSession!
    var queue : OperationQueue!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        start = Date().toMicroSeconds()
        print("0  ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
        session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        print("100 Start downloadApi func at: ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
        response = downloadApi(response, stringUrl: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song")
        print("110 Return from downloadApi func at: ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
        print("120 Without DownloadOperation the next statements failed!!")
        let txtFromDecodedApi = "Count: = " + String(self.response!.results.count) + "\nTrack Name: " + self.response!.results[1].trackName + "\nCollection Name: " + self.response!.results[1].collectionName
        print(txtFromDecodedApi)
        print("130 Success ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
    }
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        // find all possible documents directories for this user
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        
        // just send back the first one, which ought to be the only one
        return paths[0]
    }
    func downloadApi<T:Decodable> (_ t:T, stringUrl: String) -> T {
        var apiReadNotCompleted:Bool = true
        var apiReadCompleted = false
        var decodedResult: T?
        let completionOperation = BlockOperation {
            print("6  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            print("6   Finished download all")
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: self.urlLocal!) {
                print("7  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
                print("7   readApiJson() ",data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3])
                // here is where you could write the Api download to
                // local file of different types
                // self.writeApiToLocalFile(data: data)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let jsonDecoded = try? decoder.decode(type(of:t), from: data) {
                    decodedResult = jsonDecoded
                    print("8  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
                }
                print("9  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            }
            //self.progressLabel.text = self.response!.results[0].trackName
            print("10 ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Axel Kee in the class DownloadOperation : Operation
                // I borrowed provided for a cancel operation
                // self.cancelButton.isEnabled = false
            }
            print("11 ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            apiReadCompleted = true
        }
        if let url = URL(string: stringUrl) {
            print("1  ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            let operation = DownloadOperation(session: self.session, downloadTaskURL: url, completionHandler: { (localURL, urlResponse, error) in
                print("1a \nlocalURL ",localURL!)//; print("1aa \nurlResponse\n",urlResponse!,"\n\nend")
                self.urlLocal = localURL
                if error == nil {
                    print("2  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("3  ",self.printMiilliSecondsFStart())
                        //self.progressLabel.text = "\(index + 1) / \(urls.count) files downloaded"
                        print("3a  Api file download complete")
                    }
                }
            } )
            print("4  ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
            completionOperation.addDependency(operation)
            self.queue.addOperation(operation)
        }
        else {print("4a Bad url = ", stringUrl)}
        print("5   Before end ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
        self.queue.addOperation(completionOperation)
        // Axel Kee in the class DownloadOperation : Operation
        // I borrowed provided for a cancel operation
        // self.cancelButton.isEnabled = true
        apiReadNotCompleted = true
        apiReadCompleted = false
        while (apiReadNotCompleted) {
            if apiReadCompleted {
                print("5   Middle Api file read ")
                apiReadNotCompleted = false
            }
        }
        print("5   After end and exit ",printMiilliSecondsFStart())
        return decodedResult!
    }
    func printMiilliSecondsFStart() -> String {
        let et = Float(Date().toMicroSeconds() - start)/1000.0
        return "Elapsed Time in milliseconds: " + String(et)
    }
    func printDate(string: String) {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
        print(string + formatter.string(from: date))
    }
}
extension Date {
    func toMicroSeconds() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000000)
    }
}
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}
// Copyright © 2019 fluffy. All rights reserved.
// Axel Kee 7 May 2019
// https://fluffy.es/download-files-sequentially/
// SequentialDownload-master
class DownloadOperation : Operation {
    private var task : URLSessionDownloadTask!
    enum OperationState : Int {
        case ready
        case executing
        case finished
    }
    // default state is ready (when the operation is created)
    var state : OperationState = .ready {
        willSet {
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            self.willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
        didSet {
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            self.didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }
    }
    override var isReady: Bool { return state == .ready }
    override var isExecuting: Bool { return state == .executing }
    override var isFinished: Bool { return state == .finished }
    init(session: URLSession, downloadTaskURL: URL, completionHandler: ((URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)?) {
        super.init()
        // use weak self to prevent retain cycle
        task = session.downloadTask(with: downloadTaskURL, completionHandler: { [weak self] (localURL, response, error) in
            // if there is a custom completionHandler defined,
            // pass the result gotten in downloadTask's completionHandler to the
            // custom completionHandler
            if let completionHandler = completionHandler {
                // localURL is the temporary URL the downloaded file is located
                completionHandler(localURL, response, error)
            }
            // set the operation state to finished once
            // the download task is completed or have error
            self?.state = .finished
        })
    }
    override func start() {
        // if the operation or queue got cancelled even
        // before the operation has started, set the
        // operation state to finished and return
        if(self.isCancelled) {
            state = .finished
            return
        }
        // set the state to executing
        state = .executing
        print("000 Start downloading \(self.task.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
        // start the downloading
        self.task.resume()
    }
    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        // cancel the downloading
        self.task.cancel()
    }
}
 Results
 0   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 0.147
 100 Start downloadApi func at:  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 1.473
 1   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 1.777
 4   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 26.885
 5   Before end  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 26.963
 000 Start downloading https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song
 1a
 localURL  file:///Users/charlescole/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FB473C00-0C85-4B30-8DD6-9D7408BA0BD2/data/Containers/Data/Application/6E87F4AE-59BC-4650-A5C2-70FEACEB516D/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_GFf5Jt.tmp
 2   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 183.764
 6   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 183.946
 6   Finished download all
 7   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 184.147
 7   readApiJson()  10 10 10 123
 8   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.018
 9   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.031
 10  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.039
 11  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.056
 5   Middle Api file read
 5   After end and exit  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.072
 110 Return from downloadApi func at:  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.083
 120 Without DownloadOperation the next statements failed!!
 Count: = 50
 Track Name: Shake It Off
 Collection Name: 1989
 130 Success  Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 186.106
 3   Elapsed Time in milliseconds: 194.89
 3a  Api file download complete
```